# Can we write this without an import statement by any chance? Just wondering

Tags: java

I always tend to write the import statement whenever i am writing a program so Im just wondering if i can write it differently without the import and still compiles. Thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class kk {

    public static void main (String args){
        Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
    }

}
```

Comment: What good will it do?

Comment: I know it is better with import but is there a way we can do it without it?

Comment: Sure. `java.util.Scanner in = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Import statements just allow you to use the shorthand name for the Object. You can just specify the whole name:

```
java.util.Scanner in = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
```

However there isn't really any reason why not to use the import.

From the [docs tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html):

> However, if you are trying to use a member from a different package and that package has not been imported, you must use the member's fully qualified name, which includes the package name.